# Publishing an Apk With maxSdkVersion Value For Filtering at Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I've an apk at Google Play with properties below:

```
android:versionCode="1000"
android:versionName="1"

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Devices with api level `8 (2.2 FROYO)` and `7 (2.1 ECLAIR_MR1)` had a problem wiht this apk because of an unsupported method at those api levels. Anyway, I know the reason of the problem and the solution for it. But I don't want to push update to all of my clients(9+). So I created a version of an apk with properties below:

```
android:versionCode="1001"
android:versionName="1.1"

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="8"/>
```

This version of my apk was going to be seen by only the devices which are at api level 7 and 8.

But when I tried to publish it at Google Developer Console, I got error below:

```
This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels 7-8 to API levels in range 9+ should downgrade from version 1001 to version 1000, which would occur when 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.location.NETWORK, android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.WIFI].
```

[I've already read documents about maxSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max) (I know that it is not suggested to be used)

[Also tried similar error's solution at adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1352362) which didn't help me.

Did you have the same situation? Any solutions/workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, the solution is to drop `android:maxSdkVersion` (universally ignored) and to *also* publish a `1002` version for higher API levels. See http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#HowItWorks and http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CreatingApks. Or, better yet, fix your app to work for all devices from a single source, such as via checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` at runtime to determine how to handle those API calls that gave you problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare so I have no chance to publish an apk for only visible to devices with api level 7 and 8 while I have an apk which is visible from 7 to 19?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can follow the advice in the first two sentences of my comment, including clicking on the links and **reading the documentation**.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the links and the information you've shared. To clarify the issue; I can not publish a "single" apk which is described as version 1001 after my current apk (1000). To solve my issue, I've 2 choices: 1) I have to publish another apk with the version code 1002, which is designed for +9 devices. 2) I have to publish my single apk(1001) for all api levels without maxSdkVersion. Both solutions will be an update to 9+ devices which I don't want.

Comment: Actually, android:maxSdkVersion isn't universally ignored, it would filter results for devices with higher API versions in Google Play. Although it's still deprecated and not recommended by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not publish a "single" apk which is described as version 1001 after my current apk (1000). To solve my issue, I've 2 choices:

1. I have to publish another apk with the version code 1002, which is
   designed for +9 devices. Because google says that if the device is upgraded(its api level increases from 8 to 9, device must get the lower version of my apk and it is forbidden.)
2. I have to publish my single apk(1001) for all api levels without
   maxSdkVersion.

Both solutions will be an update to 9+ devices which I don't want.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#HowItWorks

> ...the version codes must increase in
>   correlation with the API level support for each APK, so that users get
>   an update when **they receive a system update**.